# sed everything in front of second pipe symbol

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I just want to remove everything in front of the second pipe symbol (including the pipe symbol) up to the greater-than sign (keeping it). Sadly I am a beginner and found not a similar problem online.

e.g.

```
>ENA|FXSY01000001|FXSY01000001.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>ENA|FXSY01000001|FXSY01000002.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>ENA|FXSY01000001|FXSY01000003.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
```

**re-edit from @VJC**
New requirement for output :

```
>FXSY01000001.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>FXSY01000002.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>FXSY01000003.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
```

with shellter's suggestion it gave me following output: `awk -F\| '/^>/{print ">" $NF}1' file > newFile`

```
>FXSY01000001.1
>ENA|FXSY01000001|FXSY01000001.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>FXSY01000002.1
>ENA|FXSY01000001|FXSY01000002.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>FXSY01000003.1
>ENA|FXSY01000001|FXSY01000003.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
```

but fixed it with: `sed '/^#/ d' < inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt`

```
>FXSY01000001.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>FXSY01000002.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
>FXSY01000003.1
AAAATCTTATTTTATTTTTTCCCTGTCGGCAGCAATTCATTCACCCCCTCACTTTTTAAT
ATTTTTAACTGCAAGATGAATAAAAATAAATTTTTCTCTCCACTCCATCATCCTGCTATA
TACATTTTTACTTTTTTTAATATTTTCCTTCCAATCATCACTACTTTATTTTTATTTCC
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for honestly telling about what your tried to solve your own problem, on SO we guide each other for correct/best solution and we don't hesitate to even post our approaches(doesn't matter even if we tried with wrong approaches) in our posts; important is we should mention our efforts, keep it up and happy learning on this great site SO

Comment: `awk -F\| '{print $NF}' file > newFile` if I understand your requirement correctly. It is always good form on S.O. to include your required output from your sample input **in the body of your question** (and not as a replying comment ;-! ) . Good luck.

Comment: `sed 's/.*|//' file`?

Comment: @shellter: It did the job. Thank you very much! What would be the necessary command for the following output:  ```>FXSY01012088.1FURTHER INFO
>FXSY01012089.1FURTHER INFO
>FXSY01012090.1FURTHER INFO
>FXSY01012091.1FURTHER INFO```

Comment: See my edit. Is that the output you require? (Do you see now why it is important to include your exact required output in the body of your Q?) . If that is what you need, all you need is `awk -F\| '{print ">"$NR}' file > newFile`. Work thru the [Awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and up you game considerably ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: `cut -d\| -f 3- input` . I'm normally a fan of awk, but sometimes `cut` is appropriate.

Comment: @shellter: the second awk jeopardizes my output. I re-edited my input and output since it might further clarify my problem. William_Pursell: Cut will not do the trick since I have sequence in between  (s. re-edited input - output)

Comment: groan, genome data again ;-) . ok, `awk -F\| '/^>/{print ">" $NF}1' file > newFile` might work. Don't have time to test or explain this right now. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: It was only part of the solution but helped me still a lot (s. edit). Thank you all for the help.

Comment: yes, I was running out when I wrote that. What you want is `awk -F\| '/^>/{sub(/.*\|/,"")}1 file > newFile`. Glad you solved your problem. If you're going to be manipulating/cleaning up data a lot, I again recommend the [Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html). .Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\(.*\)/\3/'  Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:*** Using temp buffer concept of `sed` where we can keep matched regex in memory and can give them numbers too. Here I have kept everything before 1st occurrence of `|` in 1st pointer and everything after 1st occurrence of `|` to till next occurrence of `|` to 2nd position. Then keep everything in 3rd pointer. Later substituting whole line with 3rd pointer as per requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried it but it did not removed anything.

Comment: @VJC, you want to save output into Input_file itself if yes then try(this will take back of Input_file 1st and then edit the actual Input_file and save output into Input_file itself), `sed  -i.bak 's/\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\(.*\)/\3/'  Input_file` and let me know then?